# Adding multiple instances of another class into a LinkedList

Tags: java, object, linked-list

I am attempting to create a list of bank records. Each record consists of a first name, last name, phone number, and balance. In the first class I ask the user for this information, then create a new instance of the records class to add to the list. However, as I add more records it replaces all records with the most recent one, which you can see with my showAllRecords() method. How do I fix this?

The add and showAllRecords method in the main class. These methods are called from a switch statement in the main method:

```
private static void showAllRecords() 
{
    if(records.bankRecords.size() == 0)
        System.out.println("There are no records.");
    else
        for (int i = 0; i < records.bankRecords.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(records.bankRecords.get(i));
        }

}

private static void add() 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the first name: ");
    String firstName = scan.next();
    System.out.print("Please enter the last name: ");
    String lastName = scan.next();
    System.out.print("Please enter the phone number: ");
    String phoneNumber = scan.next();
    System.out.print("Please enter the balance: ");
    int balance = scan.nextInt();

    bankRecords.add(new records(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, balance));
}
```

The records class

```
public class records 
{   
public static String firstName;
public static String lastName;
public static String phoneNumber;
public static int balance;

LinkedList<records> bankRecords = new LinkedList<records>();

public records(String tFirstName, String tLastName, String tPhoneNumber, int tBalance)
{
    firstName = tFirstName;
    lastName = tLastName;
    phoneNumber = tPhoneNumber;
    balance = tBalance;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share the entire source of `records`?

Comment: Are `Records` fields static ?

Comment: We are only allowed to use a LinkedList for this assignment user2494817

Comment: The code you have presented does not explain the problem you describe.  In addition to the rest of these classes, how are you determining that records are being replaced instead of added?

Comment: why are you sure it replaces them? have you tried checking the list's size or to print all of it's content?

Comment: Remove the static keyword from the class attributes.

Comment: Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because all the fields in `records` class are `static`. Remove the `static` keyword from the declarations of fields. As they are `static` whenever you create a new object of `records` class you overwrite those `static` fields.

Static fields belong to the class not to the object.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the LinkedList instance that you have declared in records class. Why are u doing that. Declare it in your main class and try to use ArrayList which I think is better in your case. The reason is that records has static fields
2. Why your class name starts with small letter. Its a very very bad practice.

Comment: That is all true, but it doesn't answer the question. It should thus be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have an inherent planning problem.

There is a difference between the entity "Bank Record", which includes, as you said, a name, balance etc., and the entity "List of Bank Records", which includes, well, a variable number of bank records.

Your "records" class (please use a capital letter in the beginning of a class name) tries to mix both. So you have both a record and a list inside it. You should separate the two entities. You then create a new "Record", and add it to the "ListOfBankRecords" objects.

Also, it seems that you have both a variable and a variable called "records". This is also why a capital letter would have been good. You shouldn't have a variable that has the same name as a class.